# Simple regex for timeformat [year]/[month]/[day]-[hour]:[min]

Tags: php, regex

what's the simple time format regex for use on `preg_match` function
I try to find a regex for a time format exact :`2012/05/23-23:56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}
```

But that would be only a rough syntactic match. You might still want to make sure it is in fact a date and time. You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` for that with a format string like the following (untested):

```
%Y/%m/%d-%G-%i
```

Comment: Thanks Joey , Are this true too  : `/[0-9]{4}|\/[0-9]{2}|\/[0-9]{2}|-[0-9]{2}|\:[0-9]{2}/` ?

Comment: Why the alternation? I thought the string you presented in your question was a model of the things you look for. And why escape the colon? And why not use a delimiter that doesn't conflict with your pattern to avoid `e\x\c\e\ssiv\e` escaping?

Comment: I have never seen `+` or `-` being used as digits.

Comment: on digit can use `+` or `-` on inputs , for example `-2012/+05/25-24:15` with like this input , preg_match give error `: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash `

Comment: You're not supposed to use your input string as a regex pattern, I guess.